# Showing a fragment with different parameters in tabs of a view pager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I want to show a same fragment for example fragment having activities of a day of week in a viewpager for all days with different data. I will be giving the `dayNumber` parameter to each fragment being instantiated and showing related activities. The problem is I see same fragment in each tab no matter what parameter I passed. I think the last fragment added or instantiated by a pager overrides all the other tab fragments instance. Because **when I open a list item in expendableList View it is opened in all fragments of the pager**.
This is how I am using the pager and fragment.

**Pager**

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When swiping between pages, select the
            // corresponding tab.
            if (bar.getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)
                if (bar.getSelectedNavigationIndex() != position)
                    bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            // should be changed when some solution comes.
            if (tab == 0) {
                Fragment ev;
                if ((ev = (Fragment) mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mPager,
                        0)) instanceof frTimetable)
                    ((frTimetable) ev).refresh(day.Monday);
            } else if (tab == 1) {
                Fragment ac;
                if ((ac = (Fragment) mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mPager,
                        1)) instanceof frTimetable)
                    ((frTimetable) ac).refresh(day.Tuesday);
            }

            tab = position;
        }
```

**Fragement**

```
{
//class other methods
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_timetable, container, false);
    ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expActivityView);
    //I will change the list items in refresh method of the fragment for a day type
    ExpListItems = new ArrayList<Items>(Timetable_Provider.getAllActivites());
    ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(getActivity(), ExpListItems);
    ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instantiateItem()` is certainly not what you want. That is called by `ViewPager`, not by a consumer of a `ViewPager`.

Normally, you would provide the data to the `ViewPager` as part of setting up the pages, inside of your `PagerAdapter`. For example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/TabPager) uses the arguments `Bundle` to pass the page number of the page to the `Fragment` that is the implementation of the page.

If the data inside a page needs to be updated, ideally the page itself determines on its own that this is needed and handles it. Or, use an event bus (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto) to publish information that relevant pages can pick up. There is no great way to get at an existing page from outside of the page itself using `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (e.g., to have an activity push data into a page), which is one of the reasons [I wrote `ArrayPagerAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager#other-useful-methods).